# sdk grails and lazybones init fatal error

Tags: grails, groovy, lazybones

I can't use grail and lazybones installed via sdkman.
I have got fatal errors.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

$ java -version

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

$ sdk version

SDKMAN 5.7.2+323

$ sdk install grails

$ grails -version

```
| Grails Version: 3.3.8
| Groovy Version: 2.4.15
| JVM Version: 9-internal
```

$ sdk install lazybones

$ lazybones -version

Lazybones version 0.8.3

$ grails create-app --stacktrace helloworld

```
Resolving dependencies..
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:292)
    at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:54)
    at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:50)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.MavenProfileRepository.<init>(MavenProfileRepository.groovy:53)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.createMavenProfileRepository(GrailsCli.groovy:334)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:235)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

$ lazybones list
Can't connect to pledbrook/lazybones-templates: Unable to make member of class sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl accessible:  module java.base does not export sun.net.www.protocol.https to unnamed module @75f65e45
```

Comment: So removing lazybones this works just fine?

Comment: @cfrick Yes it is. But why?!

Answer (score 0):

To me that looks like an SSL handshake error when grails is doing some of its initialisation work for create app. It might be attempting to pull down some required jar files etc.

What does `sdk list grails` show? 
What does `which grails` and `which java`return?

I've not used jdk 9 heaps so might be worthwhile investigating changing that also. I think you'll find switching to jdk8 will have better results. Each jdk comes with a list of standard root certificate authorities it trusts. 
Maybe with the recent security issues like the one surrounding the Symantec CAs jdk9 might have removed these but the server grails is connecting to is still using one perhaps.

Edit: I think you may also have been using an internal development build version of Java 9 jdk. as you reported to using build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd
Try using jdk 8 or installing a newer version of Java 9.